# Kotlin data class implementing Java interface

Tags: java, overriding, kotlin, data-class

I'm trying to introduce Kotlin into my current project. I've decided to begin with entities, which seem to map perfectly to data classes.
For example I have a data class:

```
data class Video(val id: Long, val ownerId: Long, val title: String, val description: String? = null,
             val imgLink: String? = null, val created: Date? = null, val accessKey: String? = null,
             val views: Long? = null, val comments: Long? = null, val videoLink: String? = null): Entity
```

Which implements Java interface:

```
public interface Entity {
   Long getId();  
}
```

But for some reason compiler doesn't understand that method is implemented already:

> Class 'Video' must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract fun getId(): kotlin.Long! defined in net.alfad.data.Entity

Do I have to use any additional keywords for id param? What does "!" mean in the signature?

Comment: `!` in the signature means that this is a platofrm type, i.e. a type coming from Java. You can find out more about that [in the docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem here is that Kotlin loads the Java class `Entity` first and it sees `getId` as a function, not as a getter of some property. A property getter in a Kotlin class cannot override a function, so the property `id` is not bound as an implementation of the `getId` function.

To workaround this, you should override the original function `getId` in your Kotlin class. Doing so will result in JVM signature clash between your new function and `id`'s getter in the bytecode, so you should also prevent the compiler from generating the getter by making the property `private`:

```
data class Video(
    private val id: Long,
    ...
): Entity {
    override fun getId() = id

    ...
}
```

Note that this answer has been adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971284/288456

Comment: Nice answer! One more thing: does this mean that getters/setters are not regular methods as in Java?

Comment: In the resulting bytecode, and from Java's point of view, they are the same. A property getter is compiled to a method named `getXxx`. But for Kotlin (version 1.0.0), property accessors and functions are different and you can't mix the two in the hierarchy.

Comment: Is there any discussion about changing this? Is there a reason this shouldn't just _work_?

Comment: There's [an issue here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653). One of the problems is that you can't override a `val x` by a `fun getX` or vice versa in Kotlin (by design), so all kinds of complex questions show up if you have a mixed hierarchy of Kotlin and Java code where some classes use properties and some -- functions.

Comment: Base on this answer, I thought moving the interface to Kotlin as well would solve the issue, but it doesn't, is that because the bytecode is still created as if it was a java class because I'm still in a mixed project?

Comment: @avalancha Converting the interface to Kotlin and changing get-methods to properties (`fun getX` -> `val x`) would solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your whole data class then you're not overriding getId(). I see that you have a property called id and Kotlin should generate a getter for that but that won't be marked with the override keyword which you need to indicate that you're overriding an abstract function.

-- EDIT --
Alexander beat me to it! His answer is better anyway! ;)