# How to fix the conflict when implement two id interfaces?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, spring-data-commons

One interface is 'org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable', it's a java interface with a method `ID getId()` in 3rd-party lib.

Another interface is a Kotlin interface `interface IdEntry { val id: String}`.

Now my business entry needs to implement these two interfaces:

```
data class MyEntry(
  override val id: String,
  ....// more properties
) : IdEntry, Persistable<String>
```

I use IntelliJ IDE to code and the error is:

```
Class 'MyEntry' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member 
@Nullable public abstract fun getId(): String! 
defined in org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable
```

How can I fix this?

I also tried below code: (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631290/kotlin-data-class-implementing-java-interface#answer-35631823))

```
data class MyEntry(
  private val id: String,
  ....// more properties
) : IdEntry, Persistable<String> {
  override fun getId() = id
  ...
}
```

But this also failed:

```
Cannot weaken access privilege 'public' for 'id' in 'IdEntry'
```

Comment: What do you think this means: Cannot weaken access privilege 'public' for 'id' in 'IdEntry' ?

Comment: That's the error tip from IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Yes, that I understand, but do you know what it means? Do you know what IntelliJ is trying to tell you?

Comment: I know what it means but don not know how to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a platform declaration clash that cannot easily be resolved as long as `MyEntry` implements both `IdEntry` and `Persistable`.

However, there is one way, if you declare the property that is inherited by `IdEntry` as a `@JvmField`:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable

data class MyEntry(@JvmField override var id: String) :
        IdEntry, Persistable<String> {

    override fun getId(): String? = this.id

    override fun isNew(): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
}

interface IdEntry {
    val id: String
}
```

This works, because the clash occurs when the Kotlin compiler generates getters and setters for the `id` property as long as it has no `@JvmField` annotation.

The getter clashes with the function `getId()` inherited from `Persistable`.

By adding `@JvmField`, the generation of the getter for the `id` from `IdEntry` is avoided, thus preventing the clash.

Comment: When compile by kotlin-1.6.10，this way compile failed with 'JvmField cannot be applied to a property that overrides some other property'. See <https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32753>. How to fixed it?