# Kotlin interface a java class: Accidental override

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a third party java library with a class like

```
public class ThirdParty  {
    public String getX() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also have an interface in kotlin like

```
interface XProvider {
    val x: String?
}
```

Now I want to extend the `ThirdParty` class and implement the `XProvider` interface. This has been working fine in my legacy java code:

```
public class JavaChild extends ThirdParty implements XProvider {}
```

However, I would like to write as much kotlin as possible and am trying to convert my java classes to kotlin. Sadly, the following does not work:

```
class KotlinChild: ThirdParty(), XProvider
```

Error is

```
class 'KotlinChild1' must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract val x: String? defined in XProvider
```

However, if I do something like

```
class KotlinChild1: ThirdParty(), XProvider {
    override val x: String? = null
}
```

I get

```
error: accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getX()Ljava/lang/String;)
    fun <get-x>(): String?
    fun getX(): String!
        override val x: String? = null
```

What works is the following ugly work-around:

```
class KotlinChild: JavaChild()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. I updated the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving Accidental Override errors in Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970923/resolving-accidental-override-errors-in-kotlin)

Comment: According to the answer there it is simply impossible without the ugly java workaround. That would suck a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You have a naming conflict between the XProvider interface and the ThirdParty (abstract) class. This is caused my the Kotlin compililer which compiles

```
val x: String?
```

into a valid Java method because Java does not support the inheritance of variables or properties. The valid Java method will have the name "getX()". So you have a conflict between the XProvider.getX() and the ThirdParty.getX() method. So the solution might be to rename your property "x" in your XProvider class. Or you create a second class that contains an instance of ThridParty and implements XProvider. When val x: String is called you can provide the content by getting it from your ThirdParty instance.

Example:

```
class ThirdPartyImpl: XProvider {
    private val thridPartyInstance = ThridParty()
    override val x: String? = thirdPartyInstance.x
}
```

Comment: I understand the problem and see your workaround. I have a lot of sub classes of `ThirdParty` (in my case `ParseObject`) in java which I'm trying to convert to kotlin now and this is where the problem occurred. Your solution would not only mean to change a lot of code but would also change the external interface (`XProperty`) of my library.

Comment: What is about the second solution?

Comment: The wrapper approach would mean I'd have to wrap all public methods that I use in my project internally which in my opinion is pretty ugly as well.