# How to create a data class implements Spring Secuirty specific UserDetails

Tags: spring-security, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am trying to migrate some `spring-webflux` sample codes to kotlin.

Currently I want to convert my [Spring Data Mongo](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/security-data-mongo) sample to kotlin. There is a `User`, the original Data Mongo version looks:

```
@Data
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Builder.Default()
    private boolean active = true;

    @Builder.Default()
    private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(roles.toArray(new String[roles.size()]));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }

}
```

The `UserDetails` interface includes some getXXX and isXXX methods, how to add `override` to the `username` and `password` proerpties in kotlin?

BTW: Currently I removed `UserDetails` in the kotlin version, [check here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/kotlin-gradle/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/User.kt):

```
@Document
data class User(
        @Id var id: String? = null,
        var username: String? = null,
        var password: String? = null,
        var active: Boolean = true,
        var roles: List<String> = ArrayList()
)
```

**UPDATE**:<del>How to add the `UserDetails` interface to it?</del>, [this question is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970923/resolving-accidental-override-errors-in-kotlin?rq=1).

The new problem is when use destruction, it does not work.

```
(id, username, password, active, roles) = <a user>
```

The `User` is located https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/kotlin-gradle/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/User.kt . Currently I commented out the version implemented `UserDetails`. If I use the commented codes(User:UserDetails), the `desstruction` codes in `Beans.kt` will report errors in IDE. The errors occur on `username` and `password`: **destructing declaration initializer of type User! must have a component2 function**.

Comment: Your problem is the destructuring declaration right? Can you please provide a complete code example? I don't see an error there

Comment: @s1m0nw1 Updated and added the current User class link.

Answer (score 3):

```
data class User(
        // inherits from UserDetails
        private val username: String,
        private val password: String,
        private val isEnabled: Boolean, //Disabled account can not log in
        private val isCredentialsNonExpired: Boolean, //credential can be expired,eg. Change the password every three months
        private val isAccountNonExpired: Boolean, //eg. Demo account（guest） can only be online  24 hours
        private val isAccountNonLocked: Boolean, //eg. Users who malicious attack system,lock their account for one year
        private val authorities: Set<GrantedAuthority>, 

        // inherits from Tree.If the user is not a tree structure, can be ignored
        val id: Long,
        val parentId: Long? = null, 
        val lft: Int? = null, // preorder tree traversal algorithm
        val rgt: Int? = null, // preorder tree traversal algorithm
        val depth: Int? = null, // or levels
        val isLeaf: Boolean? = null, 
        val teamTotal: Int? = null, // The number of all subordinates
        val childrenTotal: Int? = null, //The number of all directly under the subordinate

        //Custom attributes
        val tenantId: Long, //We are the platform + tenant model
        val role: Set<Role>, // TENANT, SUBACCOUNT, DEFAULT_GROUP, MEMBER, GUEST
        val platform: Platform, // PC, IOS, ANDROID, WAP, INTERNAL
        val deviceToken: String? = null, //or machine code
        val ip: InetAddress //Inet4Address or Inet6Address
) : UserDetails, Tree(id, parentId) {
    override fun getUsername(): String = username
    override fun getPassword(): String = password
    override fun isEnabled(): Boolean = isEnabled
    override fun isCredentialsNonExpired(): Boolean = isCredentialsNonExpired
    override fun isAccountNonExpired(): Boolean = isAccountNonExpired
    override fun isAccountNonLocked(): Boolean = isAccountNonLocked
    override fun getAuthorities(): Set<out GrantedAuthority> = authorities
}
```